# How to get all site collections in a web application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, spsite

I want to list all site collections under my web application; the purpose is to list all mysites created by users.

Like that:

```
/members/sites/sqladmin
/members/sites/sqluser
/members/sites/sqluser1
/members/sites/sqluser2
/members/sites/user1
```

Answer (score 7):

For the purpose of accessing all site collections within a given web application there's, quite naturally, the [SPWebApplication.Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.sites.aspx) property. To get access to a particular web application you can use a code like this:

```
SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://my-web-app-url:80/"));
```

(see [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.aspx) as well).

Answer (score 2):

Use `SPWebApplication.Sites` property for that.

Answer (score 0):

On the Central Administration home page, click Application Management.

On the Application Management page, in the Site Collections section, click View all site collections.

The Site Collection List page lists all the site collections in the Web application.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to programmatically get the all site collections of the web application.
url parametter = web application url.

```
        public DataTable GetAllSiteCollections(string url)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("URL");
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPWebApplication webApplication = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri(url));
                foreach (SPSite site in webApplication.Sites)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { site.Url, site.Url });

                }

            });

            return dt;
        }
```